# All Wi Fi networks disappears once I manually disconnect a network

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, network-manager

I'm facing WiFi issues in my system. I have dual boot laptop. My Wi Fi works fine in Windows 10 but not in Ubuntu. When I log in, I can see all networks and can connect easily. But as soon as I disconnect it, everything disappears.

Even the following command shows 0 results

`nmcli dev wifi`

What can be the issue?

Here's the output of  **lspci -v**

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Memory at a3100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-e0-4c-ff-fe-87-2b-01
    Capabilities: [150] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [158] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I'm running 17.04 (4.10.0-33-generic #37) on a Dell XPS13:

```
3a:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

WiFi networks reappear after I restart the Network Manager

```
# service network-manager restart
```

Advice is welcome.

Comment: This doesn't work at all.